# im fetching images from an api in react but just show me the path i need it to show me the image so i can get it from my localhost

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, react-hooks, fetch

```
  import './projects.css';
  import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
  import Hero from '../../components/project/Hero';
  import Nav from '../../components/project/Nav';
  import Card from '../../components/project/Card';
  import Modal from '../../components//project/Pop';
  import axios from "axios"


  function Projects() {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("All");
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null)
  const [selectedModalImage, setSelectedModalImage] = useState(null)

  const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/projects'
  });

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  api.get('/')
  .then(res => setProjects(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  const openModal = (title, image) => {
  console.log(image)
  setSelectedItem(title)
  setSelectedModalImage(image)
  setShowModal(prev => !prev );
  };

   const filteredCards = projects.filter(item => {
  return item.category === selectedCategory || selectedCategory === 'All';
  });

  const cards = filteredCards.map(item => {
  return <Card
  key={item._id}
  image={item.image}
  title={item.title}
  modalImage={item.modalImage}
  price={item.price}
  onClick={() => openModal(item.title, item.Modalmage)}
  />
  });


  return (
  <div className="pApp">
  <Hero />
  <Nav handleSelectedCategory={setSelectedCategory} selectedCategory={selectedCategory} />
  <section className="pcards-list">
    {cards}
  </section>
  { showModal && <Modal 
    title={selectedItem}
    modalImage={selectedModalImage}
    showModal={showModal}
    setShowModal={setShowModal} /> 
  }
  </div>
  );
  }`

  export default Projects;
```

I tried to pass the data as props to local src it works but it doesnt work from localhost

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear how you trying to show the image, but in the simplest case, you need just an img tag and a link to the localhost, e.g.:

```
<img src={'/public/images/logo.png'} />
```

Also, you can use imports, like this:

```
import image from './image.png';

// .....

<img src={image} />
```

or create a full image URL, including your localhost, e.g.:

```
<img src="localhost:3000/public/images/image.png" />
```

Can you create an online demo with your problem?